# Extending the use-mention distinction to account for variables and predicates

Tags: symbolic-logic, analytic-philosophy, mathematical-logic

When we talk about the use-mention distinction, often the following is said:

> To use an expression means to refer to its meaning, to mention an
> expression means to refer to the expression itself.

I feel this definition is too narrow and accounts for only logical constants (that have a meaning).

I feel the idea of use-mention can be broadened to include expressions like variables and predicates. For instance, a variable may serve as a placeholder in a discussion and can be said to be *used*. When it's the variable itself being talked about we can say it's being mentioned. Similarly, I could *use* a predicate to form statements by replacing the variables in it, but I may also talk about the predicate as an expression itself, where it would be said to be *mentioned*.

I was interested to know if there is a broader definition of what it means to *use* an expression and *mention* it, that accounts for expressions like variables and predicates.

Comment: Not very clear to me... in a math log textbook we find " 'x' is a variable", meaning the symbol and we find the expression "x is a numer" meaning a statement about numbers.

Comment: Variables and predicate expressions are expressions, so what makes you think the distinction does not apply to them as written? The definition uses the word "expression"; why do you think it means "logical constant"?

Comment: @DavidGudeman I have trouble with the word "meaning". Constants have a meaning (the thing that they denote). Variables, as I understand, do not have a meaning, they simply act as placeholders for constants. Similarly, predicates don't have a meaning, it's only when we replace variables by constants in predicates, that a predicate gives a statement that has a meaning. So I feel the word "meaning" in the definition of use-mention, only applies to constants.

Comment: The word "meaning" is not used in that definition in a narrow technical sense. Variables, predicates, etc., all have "meanings", their functions in the language, as distinct from labels that refer to them. So the definition is already "extended".

Answer (score 3):

To expand on @David's comment, the use-mention distinction is already enough for predicates. In english, here is a list of predicates: "hot", "red", "is hungry". I have just mentioned them, but I could easily use them in a sentence.  Now, assume your object language consists only of a formal language, say FOL. Then, very clearly, you use the variable x whenever you write 'Px'. Also very clearly, you mention the variable x whenever you say "x". So this would be trivial. Lets toss that assumption in what follows.

Variables in natural language are a bit more tricky, since people do not typically use variables in the sense of mathematical logic in everyday speech (Dowty, Montague Semantics, p69 says they don't use them at all!- at least not in english). Here is one reason: recall that a sentence is a formula with free variables. A competent speaker of a natural language typically uses sentences of L, not fragments, hence all "variables" they use are bound, and typically assumed to be sorted as well (in the model-theoretic sense). If we follow Frege at this point, variables don't really have a meaning, since they don't contribute to any sentence. So we never really use them, since they don't have a meaning. Perhaps your comment is along these lines.

So on the one hand, its not really necessary that use-mention for natural language capture variables, on the other hand, it vacuously does.